# Is it possible to give html elements (i.e. divs) mass, velocity and other physics related attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I working on a website that is made up of circular divs that are in constant motion. The divs eventually collide with one another and the walls. I have done tons of research and the best solution is to use momentum which works depending on mass and velocity. This [link](https://martinheinz.github.io/physics-visual/) shows a perfect example of what I plan on making but the problem is that the colliding objects are 2D shapes in a canvas element. So is there a way of giving a div MASS and VELOCITY using HTML and vanilla JavaScript? If yes, how can I implement it?
Thankyou.

Comment: You can use `data-` attributes (`data-mass`, `data-velocity`, etc...).

Comment: I think that would be useful. Thankyou for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This should help you

Yes, you can use "data-..." attributes.

For example:

```html
<div id="car" data-mass="20" data-velocity="44"></div>
```

If you need to get the value of that attribute, use the code below

```js
// Get the car element
const car = document.getEelementById('car');

// Get the mass of the car
const mass = car.getAttribute("data-mass");
```